# Does it better to generate all random numbers outside the loop or generate it on the fly

Tags: performance, matlab, random

Usually if in every iteration you need to generate a random number, it's better to generate all the random numbers once at the beginning and then in each iteration, you retrieve the number you generated from the table.

However, I encounter a problem today which against this intuition. I have a numeric vector of length N, in each iteration, I have to reshuffle the order of this vector and do something.

I implement 2 ways: the first one is exactly as I just described, i.e., in each iteration, I call function

```
V = randperm(N)
```

In the 2nd method, before the loop, I call function

```
W = arrayfun(@(x)randperm(N),(1:T-1)','UniformOutput',0);
W = cell2mat(W);
```

Here `T` is the total number of iterations. Then in each iteration, I just retrieve the row from the matrix `W`. Then the rest of the code for 2 methods are exactly the same.

However, I find the 2nd code is much slower than the 1st one (I checked that the command of: `W = arrayfun(@(x)randperm(N),(1:T-1)','UniformOutput',0);` does not take much time). I run the profiler, I find that in the 2nd code call the function `ismember>ismemberR2012a` 3 times more than the 1st code. I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: Is there a requirement to use `randperm` and not something like `randi` which can give you a large random matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you should note that both functions `randperm` and `arrayfun` are implemented as `mex` files. So my first guess would be that the `arrayfun` is a process that is calling the `randperm` and storing its result in a `cell` and repeating this process. That makes it a bit slower. If you try to do the same in the first solution it will cost more.
I performed some tests as well.
I do not know the scale of `N` and `T`. But still I tested the functions on my machine

```
N=10000;
T = 1000;
tic;
for ii=1:T-1
    V=randperm(N);
end
toc;
tic;
W = arrayfun(@(x)randperm(N),(1:T-1)','UniformOutput',0);
W = cell2mat(W);
toc;
```

And the result is:

For `N=10000` and `T=1000`:

```
Elapsed time is 0.849627 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.996933 seconds.
```

I think the reason is that the first solution is called `T-1` times, whereas the second one is called only once. And it has to manage the big cell assignment.

[image]

Even doing this does not improve the performance of the code that much:

```
tic;
for ii=1:T-1
Z = arrayfun(@(x)randperm(N),ii,'UniformOutput',0);
end
toc;

Elapsed time is 0.827387 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.966013 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.951093 seconds.
```

Then running the profiler:
[image]

- If you can generate random numbers on the fly, what is the point of generating and storing them and then loading them again when needed?
- the numbers are collected in different runs and obviously due to the stochastic nature of the execution time they are not consistent.

Comment: So it seems it is better just run randperm(N) in each iteration separately. Will memory also be an issue in this case? Name if we call randperm(N) in each iteration, it consumes very little memory than we do one call without loop

Comment: I would go with calling it once when it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Just making a note that if `N` is smaller than 10, you might want to use [`perms`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html):

Before the loop:

```
% get all available permutations:
W = perms(1:N);
% get a list of T random permutations from W:
p = randi(length(W),T,1);
```

and then use `p` and `W` inside the loop:

```
V = W(p(k),:); % for iteration k
```